# Expected Declaration

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

I am getting an error when running my app in Swift using the latest version of Xcode 7.1.

Error given: **Expected Declaration'** The fix provided by SwiftArchitect worked but I am getting this new error when running the code.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // ..
    return true
}
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    let rootVC: MyViewController = MyViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.window!.rootViewController = rootVC

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the Swift migration tool?  That function declaration is wrong.

In an empty Swift iOS project `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is setup like this:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

    let rootVC: MyViewController = MyViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.window!.rootViewController = rootVC

    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Your full AppDelegate should look like this:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

        let rootVC: MyViewController = MyViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.window!.rootViewController = rootVC

        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

Comment: Maybe you want to emphasize **Swift migration tool**, since this code has clearly not been created with Xcode 7.1

Comment: That worked! But when I cleaned the build and ran the code again it gave me a new error: "Expected Declaration" what now?

Comment: @ArmaniRouse can edit your question and post the full code that is giving you that error?

Comment: Pardon, I'm new at programming

Comment: @JAL Here is the line of code the new error is give on: self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

Comment: @ArmaniRouse that line isn't giving me an error.  Can you please edit your question with the full code you are trying?  I have edited my answer to show what your method should look like.

Comment: @ArmaniRouse you're returning true before doing anything else.  Look at my answer, I've adjusted my code.

Comment: @JAL ok that did work but now it gives me the very same error but on the very last line in which there is no code there. I cleaned the build and ran it but it gives me "Expected Declaration" at the very bottom where there is no code

Comment: @ArmaniRouse You must be copy-pasting something wrong.  If you remove the old function completely and use this new function, you will not have any issues.

Comment: I removed the old code and pasted what you provided. You only included the part that needed fixing so I didnt remove anything else

Comment: @ArmaniRouse I've added an example of what your AppDelegate should look like.  Check to see if yours looks like mine.  I am not encountering any errors.

Comment: @JAL I've copied and pasted your code and am getting "Use of Undeclared type 'View Controller'"

Comment: @ArmaniRouse replace `ViewController` with `MyViewController`.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

Start over.

```
Xcode > File > New > Project...
```

**Option 2**

Cleanup automatically.

```
Xcode > File > Edit > Convert > To Latest Swift Syntax...
```

**Option 3**

Do everything by hand.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```